# Can we explain certain light phenomenon like refraction using particle nature of light?

Tags: optics, photons, refraction, diffraction

Using Hugyen's principle and wave nature of light, refraction, diffraction are relatively simple to explain but I have been visualing a mental model for a couple of days where the photons on reach the boundary of two media, experience a difference in the structure of the medium of propagation and hence some sort of collision or change in the overall velocity vector of each photon occurs which leads to refraction. Can someone help me understand these phenomenon using particle nature?

Comment: Check this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438607/how-does-newtons-corpuscular-theory-explain-the-speeding-up-of-corpuscles-when